# Replace Activity layout with Fragment Layout

Tags: android

I have an activity, in that mail layout I have button
on click of that button I want to replace the entire activity layout with my fragment layout

how can I do this.?

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to replace your `Activity` layout is to create a `Container Parent layout` and set as the content to the `Activity` and then add the `Fragment` to the `container Layout`

```
 // create a frame layout
 FrameLayout fragmentLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
 // set the layout params to fill the activity 
 fragmentLayout.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
 // set an id to the layout
 fragmentLayout.setId(1000); // some positive integer
 // set the layout as Activity content
 setContentView(fragmentLayout);
 // Finally , add the fragment
  getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(1000,new TestFragment()).commit();  // 1000 - is the id set for the container layout
```

Comment: gives the following error: Expected Resource of type ID

Comment: When press back, not return to main activity

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `Activity` layout looks something like:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

You can replace the contents of the `FrameLayout` with your `Fragment`:

```
getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
        .commit();
```

If you want to be able to press 'back' to remove the fragment, add `addToBackStack(null)` to the `FragmentTransaction`. See the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) for more details.

Comment: I tried your code, but am getting nullpointer exception below here mTumkurCityGridFragment = //new TumkurCityGridFragment();
    (TumkurCityGridFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.layoutToadd);            mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, mTumkurCityGridFragment);                                            mTumkurCityGridFragment is null

Comment: I can't tell what your code in the comment does as it is not formatted correctly and looks like the instantiation of `mTumkurCityGridFragment` is commented out. If you're trying to load the fragment using `findFragmentById()` you will have to have already added the fragment to the layout with the id. I suggest a through read through http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the reference of [Libin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23531886/5512020]): 
His answer gives the following error: *Expected Resource of type ID*. Hence follow the following procedure

Create a resource file in values called ids

```
<resources>
    <item name="fragmentLayout" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Use this id to reference the id of the layout.

```
// create a frame layout
FrameLayout fragmentLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
// set the layout params to fill the activity 
fragmentLayout.setLayoutParams(new  ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
// set an id to the layout
fragmentLayout.setId(R.id.fragmentLayout); // some positive integer
// set the layout as Activity content
setContentView(fragmentLayout);
// Finally , add the fragment
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentLayout,new TestFragment()).commit();
```

Another method to get id for a generated layout is `fragmentLayout.setId(View.getGeneratedId());`. But it is problematic to access the id of the fragment outside the activity using this method. Hence, I would recommend the above method.